# Key Combination Order

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Not that this really matters, but what's the "standard" (or most commonly accepted) order of modifier keys in keyboard commands? For example, one would be more likely to see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> than something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

So suppose I have a hypothetical application with a lot of key commands to document. How would I order something that uses every modifier key?

e.g.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Menu</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (joke)

And what about <kbd>Fn</kbd>?
e.g. some keyboards might have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: Most people put [ctrl] before [alt] before [shift]

Comment: I suppose I see that a lot, too, but what about Super/Win?

Comment: {shrug} Don't see those much.

Comment: I would have a browse around https://shortcutworld.com/ and see how they order them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the examples in Microsoft's [guidelines for keyboard user interface design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_windows_shortcut_keys) the order of the modifiers seems to be:

```
CTRL - ALT - SHIFT - WIN - [key]
```

This is consistent with the [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/inputs/keyboards#custom-keyboard-shortcuts), which explicitly state that the correct order is:

```
Control, Option, Shift, Command.
```

For any other keys that follow, I would say that you may choose your order.

Comment: That's funny...I would have expected Microsoft to rewrite the convention and make the `Win` modifier come first.

Comment: @Twisty: This also was a surprise for me, but I theorize that Microsoft thinks of `Win` as being more than just a modifier.

Comment: I would've thought that [Win] would come between [Ctrl] and [Alt] due to the keyboard layout.

Comment: The 'Win' key didn't exist until 1994 when Microsoft came out with the first 104 key, "Natural Keyboard". The 3 extra keys are 2 windows keys and the menu key which I haven't see on keyboards in a while. Windows 95 was the first OS to recognize the key. The design order was likely created in 1980 for MS-DOS 1.10. -- The Apple Command key has been on Macintosh computers since 1980, but their spec was likely written for the the Apple 1 or ][+ documentation in 1978..